# Let $y=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$, prove that $xy'=y(x+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$, prove that $xy'=y(x+1)$

My idea is to prove that the given series converges uniformly  (but I'm not sure that it converges uniformly) and then use the diffentiability to prove the problem.

Let $a_n=\dfrac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$, then we have

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{x}{n}=0<1$, thus given series converges.

That's all I get. Can anyone help me, please? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So, your power series converges. Have you tried termwise differentiation already?

Comment: You only need uniform convergence on a small neighborhood of the point $x$ you are proving the equation.  In fact, your calculus textbook has probably already done this for power series ... differentiation term-by-term is valid for them, within the radius of convergence.  So find the radius of convergence.

Comment: You can also use that $y=xe^x$ and then use the fact that $(e^x)'=e^x$. But perhaps this is what you want to prove, so I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I've tried termwise differentiation but it seems wrong. Perhaps it does not converge uniformly. By the way, its radius of convergence is $\infty$. Isn't it right.  Thanks for caring about my problem.

Comment: I understand now. It's my fault in studying the theory. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you've figured out how to do it, consider writing an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

The given power series converges for *any* $\;x\in\Bbb C\;$, or $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ (in fact, it is the function $\;xe^x\;...$) , and thus you can differentiate termwise:

$$y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}\implies xy'=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^n}{(n-1)!}=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n-1)x^n+x^n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=(x+1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=(x+1)y$$

Of course, with the exponential is nicer, simpler and shorter:

$$y=xe^x\implies xy'=x(e^x+xe^x)=xe^x(1+x)=y'(1+x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The general term in the LHS will be

$$\frac{nx^n}{(n-1)!}$$

and that in the RHS,

$$\frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}+\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}.$$

You can easily identify.

Special care must be taken for $n=1$, but on both sides you get $x$ (also, with $(-1)!=\infty$ the identity remains valid).

Comment: Alternatively, if one wishes to be careful: separate out any constant terms in your series before differentiating.